# Any way to create referential integrity based on data values?

Tags: postgresql

following is a simplified illustration

```
TABLE : EMPLOYEE (TENANT_ID is a FK)
ID   |    NAME   | TENANT_ID   
1    | John      |  1

TABLE DEPARTMENT
ID   |   NAME  | TENANT_ID
1    | Physics | 1
2    | Math    | 2


TABLE : EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENTS (Join between employee and department)
ID | EMPLOYEE_ID   | DEPARTMENT_ID 
1  | 1             | 1
```

Is there a way to fail inserting data into EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENTS if EMPLOYEE value is for TENANT 1 and DEPARMENT_ID is from TENANT 2? e.g. where employee_id=1 belongs to tenant=1 and department_id=2 belongs to tenant=2

```
ID |  EMPLOYEED_ID  | DEPARTMENT_ID
2  |   1            | 2
```

Is there a way to prevent such data insertion either at an app or db level. PS> no room for using triggers and don't want to use triggers.

Comment: do you want smth like FK referencing JOINed two tables?.. or `EMPLOYEED_ID` value to always match `DEPARTMENT_ID` value?

Comment: BCNF: If they are to be the same, tenant_id is transitively dependent (on department_id) , so you can remove it from employee. There is an edge-case for employees that are not (yet) part of any department. (NB: if the employee is part of two departments, these should have the same tenant_id. looks like a 4NF problem... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without triggers, the only way to do this is copy the tenant id so it appears in every table, and use composite primary or unique constraint and a composite foreign key.

e.g. if you had a `UNIQUE` constraint on `EMPLOYEE(TENANT_ID, ID)` and on `DEPARTMENT(TENANT_ID, ID)` you could add a `FOREIGN KEY (TENANT_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (TENANT_ID, ID)` and `FOREIGN KEY (TENANT_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (TENANT_ID, ID)`.

This requires that the join table incorporate the `TENANT_ID`.

I suggest defining the `PRIMARY_KEY` of `EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENTS` as `(TENANT_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID)` and getting rid of the useless surrogate key `ID` on the `EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENTS` table, unless your toolkit/framework/ORM can't cope without it.